# Linux doesn't recongnize recent installations

Tags: ubuntu, apt, virtualbox

I'm working inside a virtual machine, and I don't know why software installation does not work. I have to restart my machine, but that is not an option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install docker.io
```

It's simple like that.